Remove Resource Leveling from MS Project without reverting schedule
I have a number of complex MS Project files where we have used resource leveling to optimize the schedule.
We need to import these Project files into another application (Windchill ProjectLink), however it doesn't support resource leveled Project files. The vendor work around is to remove resource leveling, but that screws the project schedule.
Is there some quick way to save or export a resource leveled Project with the schedule set? Noting the projects will likely need to be regularly exported, resource leveled again and re-imported.

First of all, this part of the forum is focused on programming. Your question is of a general issue and rightly belongs on the Project Management part of the forum. Second, leveling does NOT optimize a schedule, it helps to alleviate resource overallocation but that is not optimization. Third, the Windchill ProjectLink may not support resource leveling but are you saying it won't even import a leveled file? I find that hard to believe because there is nothing unique about a leveled Project file. How exactly does ProjectLInk import Project files?
